# how to Handle missing values in bool column in python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a logical column

```
df['Employed'].dtypes
Out[3]: dtype('O')
```

values showing

```
df['Employed'].value_counts()
Out[4]:
False    156133
True      13271
Name: Self_Employed2, dtype: int64
```

unique showing nan

```
df['Employed'].unique()
Out[5]:array([nan, False, True], dtype=object)
```

Number of missing

```
df['Employed'].isnull().sum()
Out[6]: 21210
```

I am trying to convert logical to string and change 'nan' to 'False', then Change 'False' to 'No' and 'True' to 'Yes',
Triied to convert 'nan' as 'False' using fillna(False), its not working
Tried using str.replace('False','No') that's also not working

I need

```
Out[7]:
False    177343
True      13271
Name: Employed, dtype: int64
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use try replace missing values by [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) with `False` without `'` for boolean:

```
df.Employed = df.Employed.fillna(False)
```

Or remove missing values by [`Series.dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dropna.html):

```
df.Employed = df.Employed.dropna()
```

Comment: filling 'False' creates new category as array(['False', False, True], dtype=object), False is bool here, I do want to remove na's

Comment: @prem - Edited answer, try `df.Employed = df.Employed.fillna(False)`